# how to make doxygen use section numbering in html

Tags: doxygen

when you declare in doxygen, in a markdown file:

```
#Section1 {#sec1}
##subsection 1.1 {#s_sec1}
```

It simply becomes in html:

## Section1

### subsection 1

while i'd like:

## 1. Section1

### 1.1 subsection 1

In pdflatex it gets numbered automatically. Is there a way to have numbers also in html ? I find the font size change not sufficient.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? Kind regards.

Comment: unfortunately, i didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible to get them numbered automatically for HTML pages. The reason is that in contrast to books HTML documents are organized and readed differently. Whereas you have in books a chronological order of chapters, the HTML documents are organized in unordered single pages where a page is not necessarily comparable to a chapter in a book. The main problem is that these pages are not ordered in any chronological way, the only way to access such a page is that this page is linked in any (ordered or unordered) index or linked from another page. Whereas books have only a (1-dimensional) sequence, a website is more organized like a mesh, where each page can reference each other page. This is the big advantage (or sometimes the big disadvantage) of a website, that the readers can decide themselfes in which order they want to read the information.

Comment: hi! i really mean inside one page, not all over the doc.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with doxygen using a style sheet.

Create a file containing:

```
body {counter-reset:section;}
h1 {counter-reset:subsection;}
h2 {counter-reset:subsubsection;}
h1:before
{
counter-increment:section;
content:counter(section) ". ";
}
h2:before 
{
counter-increment:subsection;
content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
h3:before 
{
counter-increment:subsubsection;
content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "." counter(subsubsection) " ";
}
```

Then set HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET to point to the file you just created.