# Is it possible to use CSS counter-set to assign chapter numbers to Doxygen files separately?

Tags: css, doxygen

Is there any way to add CSS code to individual Doxygen pages

Writing a specification in Doxygen, I subdivide the overall document into multiple chapters, each contained into one Doxygen file. I now use the example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352152/how-to-make-doxygen-use-section-numbering-in-html/59910700#59910700) to add section numbering, which works fine. However I would like to add a chapter number to the scheme and use the CSS counter-set to assign a custom number to each chapter/Doxygen file. Is there any way to do this in Doxygen?

I'm thinking of something line this (from the post referenced above) that is included into the HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET:

```
body {counter-reset:section;}
h1 {counter-reset:subsection;}
h2 {counter-reset:subsubsection;}
h1::before {
    counter-increment:section;
    content:counter(chapter) "-" counter(section) " ";
}
h2::before {
    counter-increment:subsection;
    content:counter(chapter) "-" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
h3::before {
counter-increment:subsubsection;
content:counter(chapter) "-" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "." counter(subsubsection) " ";
}
.toc h3::before {
    content: "";
}
```

I would need however to get a:

```
counter-set: chapter=1;
```

and equivalent into each dox source file.

Comment: This is almost certainly possible, but without some representative "*[mcve]*" code we can't show you how (and questions do require enough information about your problem, including that (relevant) code).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a solution. I created Chapter1.html, Chapter2.html, ... and used \htmlinclude to import those into the dox files directly after the \page command.

The extra html files do nothing but setting the chapter counter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                counter-set: chapter 1;
            }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
</html>
```

Not elegant, but seems to be working.