# Insert custom div-tag after doc-content but only in custom \page

Tags: doxygen

## Desired Result / Background

I would like to insert a custom `div` tag with and ID "*numbered-sections*" in the main content of the generated HTML documentation, i.e. directly after the `div` tag with ID "*doc-content*", like so:

```html
<div id="doc-content">
<div id="numbered-sections">
!-- window showing the filter options -->
<div id="MSearchSelectWindow"
     onmouseover="return searchBox.OnSearchSelectShow()"
     onmouseout="return searchBox.OnSearchSelectHide()"
     onkeydown="return searchBox.OnSearchSelectKey(event)">
</div>

...

</div><!-- numbered-sections -->
</div><!-- doc-content -->
<!-- start footer part -->
...
```

, but **only for my custom pages** introduced with `\page` and not the automatically generated code information.

The background is, that I want to add automatic numbering of the sections, subsections and subsubsections, as [answered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352152/how-to-make-doxygen-use-section-numbering-in-html).

But when applying that answer, also all headers in the "standard" HTML pages *Namespace Members*, *Classes*, and *Files* are altered.

To limit the scope the automatic numbering is applied at, I want to add a new `div` tag with an ID I can use for styling using my cascading style sheet.

## Failed Approach

The following does not work, as I had hoped:

**my_custom_documentation.dox:**

```
/*!

<div id="numbered-sections">

\page my_page My Page

\section my_section My Section

\tableofcontents

Some content.

</div> <!-- end of the 'numbered-sections' div-tag -->
```

The custom `div` tag is added several times (instead of only once) and only after the `<div class="textblock">...</div>` tag, which is "too late", as the table of content is rendered before, which means I have no control over it's style via a custom cascading style sheet.

## Question

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which doxygen version are you using?

Comment: I am using doxygen version 1.9.4.

Comment: The doxygen version 1.9.4 is from May 5, 2022 the current doxygen version is 1.10.0

Comment: Are you saying this is not a problem in v1.10.0?

Comment: No, I just mention the fact that there is a newer version. In the 1.10.0 version the problem is still present, most likely a separate "class" has to be added to the `\page` / `\section` ... commands, but this should be an enhancement request (on GitHub).

Comment: Done: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10711